# How to encrypt DB username and password in Springboot and hibernate or JPA(using configuration or Annotations )

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

How to encrypt DB username and password in Springboot and hibernate or JPA(using configuration file or Annotations)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JPA 2.1, which chances are in a spring-boot application you likely are; I would look at examples of `AttributeConverter` to handle this for you from the JPA perspective.